# One who laughs at their own joke

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*[Self-aggrandizing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-aggrandizing)* is a word that I have in mind, but it doesn't seem suitable to describe one who laughs at their own joke, even when nobody else does.

> He's a _______, a person who cannot help but laugh at his own jokes

Comment: There are different circumstances in which people "laugh at their own jokes". I think it would be highly proscriptive to express a general judgement on the matter. Some jokes are so compulsive that it is difficult to tell them without laughing.

Comment: Please see this guidance from Stack Exchange management regarding [***Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity***](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if this word is...erm...appropriate enough for ELU, but, according to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=laughterbater):

> **laughterbater**
>
> 1. One who makes one's self laugh, or a person who laughs at their own jokes.

So yeah. A hybrid between **laugh** and **masturbate** is your answer.

Comment: Great answer. Is it okay to pronounce **laughterbater** as **lawtar-betar**?

Comment: I'd say laffer bater, i.e exactly how *laughter* and mastur*bator* is pronounced.

Comment: laughterbation is a form of self-laugh

Comment: True, but OP only requested a word describing a person who laughs at their own joke, not why they laugh at their own joke. The intent doesn't matter, the action is.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal: In IPA, the pronunciation of *laughterbator* is /ˈlæf.tɚ.ˌbeɪ.ɾɚ/ (“LAFF-ter Bay-ter”) in American English and /ˈlɑːf.tə.ˌbeɪ.tə/ in British English. It’s identical in pronunciation to “laughter”+“baiter”.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I ain't familiar with the word IPA? Can you please tell me about it?

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal: IPA = [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)—it’s a method of *precisely* transcribing pronunciation, so we can use text, instead of audio, to talk about the exact pronunciations of words.

Answer (score 3):

He's someone who cannot **[*keep a straight face*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-a-straight-face)**

> to manage to stop yourself from smiling or laughing:
>
> - *She tried to keep a straight face but, unable to contain herself, burst into laughter.*